# Css table - fill parent or overflow when needed

Tags: css, sass

I have a table that has different sized columns. The number of columns/rows is not predefined. The goal is to have a table that, if all the cells don't fill the window, allows scrolling AND always fills entire parent area even if there are very few cells.

Separately, I can achieve them: the allowing table to be bigger than window with overriding table with:

```
table {
    display:flex; //or block
}
```

and then setting width/min-width for the cells.

I can also get "make table as big as the parent" adding the line `table-layout: fixed;` to the parent div. This makes it fill 100% of the parent area.

But I cannot have both - display:flex means the table-layout is not coming into play.

Problem with display:flex, is that when the cell width is auto (and i can't hardcode the size, since i don't know the content or the number of cells), they won't be bigger than the content, so if i have only a couple of columns/rows, they don't fill the entire parent.

The problem with table-layout is that it ignores the min-width and just squishes the cells into the parent.

is there a way to allow table-layout:fixed to respect cell min-width, or to make cells fill out the table with display:flex?

Comment: If it's a table, why arenj't you using `<table>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure it out myself - apparently `table-layout:auto`, whist most people advice against it, very much solves my specific requirements.

so, parent defines the table-layout, and the cells min-width gets respected, and the parent gets filled out 100% even if there are on a couple of cells.

Answer (score -2):

Without being able to see the code, I'd suggest looking into the [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property for your child columns.

Comment: that would require me knowing how much the cell needs to grow - and i do not know the content or the size of it beforehand.